# partial derivative with 2 variables

Tags: partial-derivative

I have a function f(x,y) with 2 variables x and y.
I calculate the partial derivative and get the following equation $$\frac{\partial f (x,y)}{\partial x}=g(y)=0$$
To solve the problem $$g(y)=a+\frac{b}{log(1+y)}+\frac{c~y}{log(1+y)}=0$$ can I use the partial derivative ?$$\frac{\partial g (y)}{\partial y}=0$$

Comment: Why do you think that derivatives are needed to solve the problem "Find $y$ such that $g(y) = 0$?"

Comment: do you propose an analytical method to solve the problem, without the need to use a software

Comment: The equation can be solved by using special functions, or using some numerical method.